# How do I learn Chess Programming?

Tags: engines, chess-algorithms

Basically I have seen that people write a lot of chess algorithms, and ask questions in this forum, which I fumble to answer appropriately. I see the code, but unable to make out whether it is correct or not?

I am myself a software professional, but I am unfamiliar with chess algorithms, or coding-related stuff. Could you please help me to suggest where I can learn these things, or I will get the explanations ?

Comment: https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/ is a good starting point. Or if you prefer reading source code, Stockfish is open source.

Comment: Stockfish source: https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- https://www.chess.com/blog/zaifrun/creating-a-chess-engine-from-scratch-part-1
- http://mediocrechess.blogspot.com (a blog that gives you some ideas how chess engine works)

How you would approach the problem:

- Check out [chessprogramming.wikispaces.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20180216204915/https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/). This'll be your reference site.
- Create an account at [talkchess.com](http://talkchess.com). All the best engine developers are there. If there's an engine question that you can't find an answer there, you won't find it anywhere else.
- Check out the TSCP engine source code. TSCP is a simpler but working implementation chess engine. Easier to read than Stockfish.
- Do something. Try to write a chess board generator. Check the reference sites above. Study how TSCP does it.
- Compare your PERF results with https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Perft
- Write a simple position evaluation with materials only. Copy the PST table from TSCP or the chessprogramming site.
- Write a simple nega-max and alpha-beta search.
- Read about UCI protocol
- Add transposition table
- Add simple null-move pruning

Comment: TSCP is where I started, I would also add that there is a nice site for writting a progam in 99 steps here: 
http://aghaznawi.comuf.com/computer%20chess/winglet/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check a very simple chess engine written in C (even simpler than TCSP) and beginners oriented you can take a look at Secondchess:

https://github.com/emdio/secondchess

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of my favorite references:

- [Bruce Moreland's Site](https://web.archive.org/web/20071026090003/http://www.brucemo.com/compchess/programming/index.htm) - Clear descriptions of basic chess programming ideas. It doesn't get into the nitty-gritty, but it's a great reference for understanding the high-level ideas.
- [ICE Chess Blog](http://macechess.blogspot.com/) - Someone documenting his journey to creating an engine from scratch. It's good for details if you can find the blog post you're looking for.
- [Chess Programming Wiki](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Main_Page) - Basically an encyclopedia of chess programming. IMO the explanations aren't suitable for beginners, but it covers basically everything under the sun.
- [Chess Algorithms](https://sites.google.com/view/noah-caplinger-math/chess) - A book on chess algorithms written for beginners. DISCLAIMER: I am the author. I hope this does not break any rules regarding self-promotion, especially given that 1. this exactly answers the question 2. it is available for free and 3. I have given my other favorite references.